# could I return a struct in main function?

Tags: c++, matlab, struct, dll

In C++ code, I want to return a struct in the function so that the function output can be called in Matlab. for example, when we create a DLL file, and call it in Matlab, the command in Matlab is usually written as:

```
  [output] = calllib(filename, function, arguments);
```

To my knowledge, return can give the output of the function, something like that:

```
int main(argument){
   .....;
   return output;
}
```

and the type of output should be the same as the type of the function(here, the function is main).
Could the type of the output be struct? or return multi results, like that:

```
int main(argument){
   .....;
   return output1, output2, output3;
}
```

Here, I paste my code, please help me to correct or give me some advice? Thanks a lot.
The cpp file is:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <string>
#include "pch.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm> 
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void addStructFields(struct c_struct st, struct s_struct ot) {
    
    double* vector4;

    vector4 = new double[st.p5];

    int i = 0;
    while (i < st.p5) {
        vector4[i] = *st.p4;
        st.p4++;
        i++;
    }

    double t = st.p1 + st.p2 + st.p3 + vector4[st.p5 - 1];
    double t2 = st.p1 - st.p2 - st.p3 - vector4[st.p5 - 1];
    
    ot.o1 = t;
    ot.o2 = t2;

    //return 0;
};
```

the header file is :

```
#ifndef PCH_H
#define PCH_H

// add headers that you want to pre-compile here

struct c_struct { 
    double p1; 
    short p2; 
    long p3; 
    double* p4;
    int p5;
};

struct s_struct {
    double o1;
    double o2;
};


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
    __declspec(dllexport) void addStructFields(struct c_struct st, struct s_struct ot);


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

Comment: The return type of `main` must always be an `int`.  The return type of any other function can be whatever you want it to be.  If you could only ever return `int`s the language would, IMHO, be useless.

Comment: This smells of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You seem to want one program to provide data to another program.  That it should be supplied by returning it from main is the wrong path.

Comment: If you want to return multiple values from your C function to MATLAB, you should create a MEX-file around this C function. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-mex-files-1.html

Comment: The second half of your question shows you are trying to write a function library. Such a library usually doesn't have a `main` to run. It has a set of functions that are explicitly called by whatever software is using the library.

Comment: Instead of returning a struct, why not pass a struct by reference into your C++ code and modify it ? The return value can then be success/failure. See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-data-array.html see the reference section. Chris Luengo's answer above also leads here with a couple clicks.

Comment: @NathanOliver, thanks, I need to find other solutions.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Mex is a good solution. the code shown in the post is a simple case, while my case is actually complex, and it seems that I have to rewrite the whole cource code if I select MEX, this method is out of my ability now.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, yes, the second half is a DLL

Comment: @kalyanswaroop. Now, I can pass a struct to C++ code, and set the struct as argument. However, I tried to modify the struct in C++ code, then I don't know how to return it. For example, I use two arguments in the function 'addStructFields', the first one is used as the inputs to the function, and the second one will be modified in the function. When I use calllib, the value of the second argument is still the same as the default.

Comment: “it seems that I have to rewrite the whole cource code if I select MEX” — No, you don’t. You write a glue layer between MATLAB and your function. This is the same as what `calllib` does automagically, but much more flexible, you can pass data in any form you can imagine and code.